# T-SQL - batch delimiter required

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I am trying to build Visual Studio solution for Azure SQL Database.

I have SQL script with `CREATE TABLE` and its extended attributes:

```sql
create table schema.table_name (
   table_name_Key integer not null,
   constraint PK_table_Name primary key (table_Name_Key, Some_Column)
)
go

if exists (select 1 from  sys.extended_properties
           where major_id = object_id('table_name') and minor_id = 0)
begin 
   execute sp_dropextendedproperty 'MS_Description',  
   'user', 'schema', 'table', 'table_name' ;
end 

execute sp_addextendedproperty 'MS_Description',  
   'This table will be used for ....', 
   'user', 'schema', 'table', 'table_name';
go

if exists (select 1 from sys.extended_properties p 
           where p.major_id = object_id('table_name')
             and p.minor_id = (select c.column_id from sys.columns c 
                               where c.object_id = p.major_id 
                                 and c.name = 'table_name_Key'))
begin
   execute sp_dropextendedproperty 'MS_Description', 
   'user', 'schema', 'table', 'table_name', 'column', 'table_name_Key';
end

execute sp_addextendedproperty 'MS_Description', 
   'Primary Key of table_name table',
   'user', 'schema', 'table', 'table_name', 'column', 'table_name_Key';
go
```

I am still getting errors when building that I am missing batch delimiter:

> Error SQL71006: Only one statement is allowed per batch. A batch separator, such as 'GO', might be required between statements.

What am I missing and where? I already tried to add `go` after `end` but still error.

Comment: In the first batch you have an `IF`, with a statement inside, followed by another statement. That's 2 statements right there... The second batch has the same error. `END` is **not** a batch separator.

Comment: this needs more go

Comment: Added complete beginning of the script

Comment: @Larnu so the go should be inside `begin`-`end` and then one another after `end`?

Comment: No, you can't separate a batch inside a `BEGIN...END`; that would generate an error as you started a `BEGIN` section without `END`ing it, and then in the latter batch tried to `END` a section without `BEGIN`ing it.. You have `IF...BEGIN {Statement 1} END {Statement 2}` That's **two** statements. Separate your 2 statements with `GO`, as the error is telling you. `IF...BEGIN {Statement 1} END` and `{Statement 2}` need to be it 2 separated batches.

Comment: Thank you. However, when I add `GO` after every `END` I get: `This statement is not recognized in this context.` poiniting on the `IF` statement

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) database projects in Visual Studio then you need to think about things differently (and work through [some of the tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/project-oriented-offline-database-development?view=sql-server-ver15), or [this one](https://microsoft.github.io/PartsUnlimited/db/200.6x-Database-SetupSSDTanddbwithVSandVSTS.html)).

Basically each object is held in a single script and you do **not** have to write conditional statements (like `IF EXISTS ...`).  You simply define the object as you want it and SqlPackage.exe works out at deploy-time what the definition should be.

A simple table with one extended property:

```
CREATE TABLE [testSchema].[table_name] (
    [table_name_Key] INT          NOT NULL,
    [Some_Column]    VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_table_Name] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([table_name_Key] ASC, [Some_Column] ASC)
);


GO
EXECUTE sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'Caption', @value = 'Some_column is a required column.', @level0type = N'SCHEMA', @level0name = N'testSchema', @level1type = N'TABLE', @level1name = N'table_name', @level2type = N'COLUMN', @level2name = N'Some_Column';
```

Define your table in a similar manner to above, press **Build** and work through the errors.